# Hiding the launcher activity from list of apps in custom launcher application in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter, android-launcher

I'm creating a launcher application, and want it to have a settings activity where the user can tweak the behaviour of the application.

But i don't want for the launcher application to show the activity which starts the launcher

> (has the intent filters `<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>` and `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>`),

and still retain that when the user presses the home button, my application comes up as a viable candidate.

So my question is, how to hide the launcher activity from the launcher so that instead of both the activities (settings and launcher), only the settings activity is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `<intent-filter>` with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER from your launcher activity, it won't show up in the list of available applications.

To change the label of the settings activity, just add

```
android:label="@string/settings_name"
```

to the `<activity>` tag for your settings activity and create an appropriate string resource.

Comment: I tried by removing those intent filters before posting the question, but then along with not showing the activity on the launcher, it also renders my launcher application useless as android doesn't recognise it as a launcher app for some reason (doesn't show it in the list of available launchers when the home button is pressed)

Comment: Dunno why the `android:label` didn't strike me. It was staring me in the face! Thanks for that.

Comment: For the launcher `Activity` you need an `<intent-filter>` with ACTION=MAIN, CATEGORY=HOME and CATEGORY=DEFAULT. That is different from the settings `Activity`, where you need an `<intent-filter>` with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER